# MVC: Show a popup window when ModelState is valid in Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, popup

In ASP.NET MVC Project, I want to inform users their project numbers if ModelState.IsValid is true in the controller, and returns to another page if users click "Ok" or close the popup window. I tried to use System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox to do it, but the popup will not show when the application is in the server.

Here is my partial code in the controller

```
// POST: CylinderReport/Create
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(ProjectCylinderReport pctForm, string yearList, string searchRptNoString, string searchPCNString, string distList)
{
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // report number auto-increment
            int maxReportNum = CylinderReportControllerHelper.GetMaxRptNo(db, ldapUtility);
            int newReportNum = 1;
            if (maxReportNum > 1)
            {
                newReportNum = maxReportNum + 1;
            };

            //var confirm = System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(("Your Report Number is " + newReportNum), "Confirm", System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            //if (confirm == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)

            return RedirectToAction("Index", new { yearList, searchRptNoString, searchPCNString, distList });
        }
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

control

```
 //var confirm = System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(("Your Report Number is " + 
     newReportNum), "Confirm", System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        //if (confirm == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)

      // Add TempData
       TempData["MsgAlert"] = "Your Report Number is " + newReportNum"";


        return RedirectToAction("Index", new { yearList, searchRptNoString, 
    searchPCNString, distList });
```

View Html Add Modal

```
<div class="modal fade text-left" id="myModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel110" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-dialog-scrollable" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header bg-success white">
                <img src="~/Content/WebSiteIMG/bell.gif" style="width:30px" />
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel110">&nbsp;&nbsp; Message &nbsp;&nbsp;</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body text-center">
                <br />
                <h5> @TempData["MsgAlert"]</h5>
                <br />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Java

```
     @if (TempData["MsgAlert"] != null)
    {
        <script>
            $('#myModal1').modal('show');
            $('#myModal1').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
                var $me = $(this);
                $me.delay(3000).hide(0, function () {
                    $me.modal('hide');
                });
            });
        </script>
    }
```